# Use position relative inside display:table-cell in Firefox. Wrapper solution prevent vertical align : middle

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code on Chrome and ie :

```
<div id="infobox_mainpic" class="DetailsMainPic" align="center" valign="middle">
   <img src="pictures/3a8ca06d8d51e76243f3d4efdc710d72.jpg" onerror="this.src='css/noload.png';">
   <div class="mainPicArrowLeftDetails" onclick="return NextPic(this,-1);"></div>
   <div class="mainPicArrowRightDetails" onclick="return NextPic(this,1);"></div>
</div>
```

the main div (infobox_mainpic) has fixed dimension 600px*450px.
My purpose is to center vertically and horizontally the img inside. Note that all image can't be wider than 600px and higher than 450px (i have a treatement).

The two div "mainpic..." are supposed to be position absolutely from the top of the main div like on this picture

[image]

To achieve this, I used on the infobox_mainpic

```
display : table-cell;
vertical-align : middle;
text-align:center;
position : relative;
```

And on the arrows, i use

```
position : absolute;
top : 130px;
```

This works on Chrome and IE.
The problem is that position relative doesn't work on Firefox. I tried to wrap everything inside a div and apply the `position : relative` but now, the arrows are not starting from the top of the main div but from the top of the image. If I set width and height to 100% for the wrapper div , then the image is not vertically aligned...

Do you see a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I have found a solution.

instead of putting the div wrapper inside infobox_mainpic, I put infobox_mainpic inside a a div with a relative position. This way, the arrows are correctly positioned and the img is still inside the table-cell div so it is correctly centered.

Answer (score 0):

use d`isplay:inline-block` instead `table-cell`. `relative` positionning will not bug anymore.

Set `line-height` equal to `height` of your boxe and `img` as `vertical-align:middle;`

arrows could be standing outside the box. `inline-block` as well and `vertical-align:middle;` so they stand aside and at middle center of the box.At this point , `position:absolute` is not necessarry anymore.

demo http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/iAlms

*going offline*

Answer (score 0):

> This works on Chrome and IE. The problem is that position relative doesn't work on Firefox.

I think that's because firefox is still following the [CSS 2.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position) for this,

> *"The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined."*

Although that has changed in CSS 3, it seems it's still to early to rely on that.

Comment: I know that, but that was not the aim of my question.