# HTML Different rendering on Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've found something which seems to be wrong as HTML rendering, from Firefox only (actually Firefox version 27).

Chrome, Safari, Opera, Internet Explorer and even I.E.8* render this html correctly :
http://jsfiddle.net/Totjoss/eMB69/4/

**even if I.E.8 is wrong elsewhere.*

As written in this sample, the `TEST` and `TEST2` must be anchored to the blue area, just like this Chrome example rendering :
[image: Chrome rendering - correct version]
And Firefox does not place the `TEST` and `TEST2` according to it correclty :
[image: Firefox rendering - wrong version]

Plus those `TEST` and `TEST2` must be hidden by the green area - as the blue one has `overflow:hidden` in its style.

It seems Firefox is doing it wrong when the parents are tabled displayed (`display:table` and `display:table-cell`).
See the JSFiddle to see the HTML structure.

So is it a bug that should be reported ?

*Though there is a solution to this : Just surround the blue area content with another div which is `position:relative` and it's fixed, but it's quite annoying and useless.*

*P.S. : Edited title.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: change `div#right` to be `position:absolute;height:100%` and it will look like your non-firefox example.

---

In firefox's rendering of your example, `div#test` and `div#test2` are way off to the left because their parent, `div#right` is styled as both `display:table-cell` and `position:relative`. The problem is,

> The effect of `position:relative` on `table-*` elements is undefined.
>   —[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

So basically, webkit have chosen to do one thing and Gecko another. Neither is wrong according to the spec, because the spec does not define the right answer.

However, if you change to `position:absolute` the children will position themselves as you expect.

More generally, I'd advise [using flexbox if you are able to](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). It's much better suited to what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: I've set `#right` to `position:absolute;height:100%` but now it is spread to the whole page and doesn't care of `#left`, so it is not really the solution.
However thank you for your MDN link ! (Sorry @Rob Sedgwick, this post answers my question better. :P But it was still quite interesting.)

Comment: Ah, sorry I might have jumped the gun a bit. Changing to `position:absolute` conflicts with `display:table-cell`. (See http://jsfiddle.net/eMB69/6/ and inspect `#right`.)

Comment: Alright, you were right ! In fact it didn't work because I left the `top:0;left:0` rules in class `abs`, though I should remove it.
This is great, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting to pick at, but also odd!

Perhaps not knowing the full reason to what you are trying to do. But making `divs` render like `tables`  and then trying to make them render like `divs` again ( *position relative et all* ) , is just asking for cross browser/device trouble.

I gave up searching for a CSS 'throw in ' to solve the problem ( there might be one ) - even if there was, does it not feel 'wrong' to you /

Hard to give an answer here, and I think you have started to answer it too, so my answer would be.

> Separate Layout elements from content elements.

Whatever we are trying to do - trying to format content/text *( the vertical align benefits you are getting from `table-cell` perhaps* ) should be done with wrappers inside your layout elements- just to be solid and safe.

Sorry hope helps! Maybe the css 'fix', will get posted

Comment: This tricky tabled HTML is, in my opinion, the best way not just to center text, but to center layouts and also to have flexible inline elements (where `display:inline-block` may not work if the blocks are larger than calculated). With just a class given to a layout, the children will center any HTML element inside.
And I don't think there is a better way to vertically center elements that have no fixed `height` that could be used for calculation with margins or relative tops.

And for the cross browser/device troubles, it also works on iOS and Android. ;) Only Firefox is doing it wrongly.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526370/position-relative-not-working-with-display-table-cell - the takeaway from it- is that position is not defined for display:table elements. Take away your left,right,top elements and you will see

Comment: You can still create the layout using divs with display inline:block and *then* markup you table like elements inside it ( tables are to markup content, why go against the flow when you don't need to ) (is my thinking here )

Comment: interestingly, you could do the reverse and mark it up as an actual `<table>` and then set `td { display:block; }` and see what fun / benefits there may be - ( now I'm just rambling ) I enjoyed your question, I never considered setting position on table elements.

Comment: I disagree with your `<table>` idea. ;) Because it is quite wrong syntaxically : Tables are only used for displayed column and rows of keys/values (like Excel) and must not be used for layouts.
If your website is analysed by Google for example, the robot would think that you are displaying information into your tables, but you are layouting various HTML contents. Though, `<table>` and `display:table` are syntaxically different, but are displayed the same. `display:table` (and all the rests) exist to avoid people to use `<table>` as a way to center HTML content.

Comment: And here is an update : http://jsfiddle.net/Totjoss/eMB69/5/, though it wasn't the issue here. I removed the tabled display of the `TEST` and `TEST2` (only absolute positionned common `<div>`s now), but the problem is about the relative parent not being very "relative" with tabled children.

Comment: got the new demo - the elements that have *display: table* type css are not designed to respect *position*

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of this. I think **cells** are not designed to respect position and size restrictions. However, why wouldn't it be logical to position a common `<table>` ? It's just a container, only its content is special.

Comment: Did you read the thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526370/position-relative-not-working-with-display-table-cell - The answer with highest votes explains it better than I am doing.

Comment: Ahh... I only read the accepted answer, sorry. Well, that means the correct solution for this is the little solution I wrote and which is written in your link :
Just adding a wrapper under the cell `<div>` fixes it. Thanks man for your help, this thread was quite interesting. :)

Comment: Good stuff. Happy Coding! All the best.

Comment: @RobSedgwick where you say "position is not defined for table elements", that's not necessarily correct; you can still have `absolute`. (Which is useful, actually - see my answer.)

Comment: @Jeremy, good stuff! A more pinpointed answer from the powers that be.